# Resources in Resource Groups are still publicly available

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have 3 Resource groups with different users and resources in each. However, all these resources can be accessed publically by anyone regardless if they are logged into any user group.

I followed the instructions here http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/security/security-tutorials/making-member-only-pages but am not sure what I did wrong.

Heres what I have:

I first created a new User Group with context: web and I checked the 'Create Parallel Resource Group' check box.

I then went to Content>>Resource Groups and dragged the pages I wanted protected into it.

[image]

I then went to Mange>>Users and added the users I wanted to be able to view these resources to the corresponding User Group. I gave them the Role of Members.

[image]

I then Flushed Permissions and Cleared the Cache.

But if I paste the URL of any of the protected pages in another browser or incognito mode I can still access the pages.

Same if I am logged in as a user who is not part of that group.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: did you log out of your manager session first - before logging in as a web context user? if you don't log out you will still have your manager context and web context.

Comment: @SeanKimball yes, I tested in another browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had set the User Group's Permission's Access Policy to `Context` rather than `Load, List and View`